# What do these arrows mean in the status bar?

Tags: functionality, system-tray, icons

After recently updating my phone<sup>1</sup>, the following arrows above the cellular signal strength indicator and WiFi icon appear periodically.

[image]

What do they indicate?

<sup>1</sup>OS version: 8.10.14176.243

Comment: to clarify, I think those arrows only apply to Nokia Lumia with Cyan Firmware update.

Comment: @VitorCanova Nope, they were added in GDR3, although apparently some operators (like AT&T in the US) disabled the feature.

Comment: @Indrek I had the GDR3 for a long time. I'm currently in Dev preview and those arrows only appeared after last week update when I received Cyan. My daughter and Wife too.

Comment: Perhaps that's when your carrier enabled the feature, then, I don't know. See the link in my answer, it says the arrows were added in 8.0.10501.127, which is GDR3 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history#Windows_Phone_8). WPCentral also ran a [story](http://www.wpcentral.com/what-do-those-arrow-icons-mean-windows-phone) on this after Lumia Black started rolling out, well before 8.1 or Cyan became available in any form.

Comment: Interesting. At the same time I also updated to Lumia Cyan (by temporarily disabling the Preview for Developers). Perhaps it coincided with my carrier switching on this feature.

Answer (score 8):

Those icons mean that your mobile or WiFi connection is being used to transfer data.

For more information, see [What do the icons on my phone mean?](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/calling-and-messaging/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean)

Comment: I don't think so. I took s screen shot with my phone saying "no service" and those arrows are still there. Looks like they mean "something is trying to use this network".

Comment: That's what the official docs say. Maybe you were still connected to WiFi? I can't test the "no service" scenario, but if I turn off WiFi and mobile data, the arrows don't show up and apps complain about not having an internet connection.

Comment: That screenshot is showing service

Comment: @RowlandShaw Mine not. Should I post a different questions? I have a screenshot  where it says "No service" and I have the sign.

Comment: I suppose you can still transmit when you can't hear the tower (or wifi); Only yesterday I was able to send an SMS when the signal was so poor that it was showing as no network signal - I interpret that as "you wouldn't stand a chance of *making* a call")

Comment: A follow-up question: Is there any way to turn these arrows off?

Comment: @Ben As far as I know it's not possible.